# How to trigger a start polygon drawing in Google Maps API?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I would like to start drawing a polygon on my map using a different button instead of the drawing manager control.

Is it possible to trigger an event that behave as pressing the drawing manager polygon control?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use a different control to start drawing a Polygon:

1. remove the existing drawing control:

```
drawingControl: false,
```

2. add your own button:

```
<input id="polygonbtn" type="button" value="Draw Polygon"/>
```

3. set the drawing mode when it is clicked:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('polygonbtn'), 'click', function() {
  drawingManager.setDrawingMode(google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON);
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/avv16bdd/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {
      lat: -34.397,
      lng: 150.644
    },
    zoom: 8
  });

  var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
    drawingControl: false,
  });
  drawingManager.setMap(map);
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('polygonbtn'), 'click', function() {
    drawingManager.setDrawingMode(google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON);
  });
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('cancelbtn'), 'click', function() {
    drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null);
  });
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
 * element that contains the map. */

#map {
  height: 100%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<input id="polygonbtn" type="button" value="Draw Polygon" />
<input id="cancelbtn" type="button" value="Cancel" />
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=drawing&callback=initMap&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk" async defer></script>
```